# Why PostgreSQL is slow and low CPU usage?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

client send more than 300 thousands of async insert queries to postgreSQL and mysql by nodejs.

postgreSQL is mush slow than mysql!!
mysql server will use more than 50% cpu but postgresql server use only about 10%.

server hardware is 8 cores cpu and 8G ram, both server have same hardware setting.

I didn't tune any SQL config file.

client config and code as below, auto replace $1 to ? in custom query function for mysql2 library when config is mysql.

```
// mysql 
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'host',
    user: 'dev_user',
    database: 'testdb',
    password: 'password',
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    maxIdle: 10,
    idleTimeout: 60000,
    queueLimit: 0,
    enableKeepAlive: true,
    keepAliveInitialDelay: 0
}).promise();

// postgresql
const Pool = require('pg-pool');
var pool = new Pool({
    database: 'testdb',
    host: 'host',
    user: 'dev_user',
    password: 'pasword',
    port: 5432,
    max: 10,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 10000,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 600000,
    maxUses: 75000
});

// logic function
async function insert_account_day_setting(insertData){
    return query('INSERT INTO user_account_day_setting (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10)', insertData)
}

async function testing_insert(){
    await pool.query('TRUNCATE TABLE user_account_day_setting')
    console.log('truncate table before insert done')

    const rows = await query(define_sql.select_user_data);

    const hourlyArray = utils.createDayHourArray();

    const insert_total_count = rows.length * hourlyArray.length;

    let finish_update_count = 0;
    const t1 = new Date().getTime();
    rows.forEach((row,idx) => {
        /** @type {Array<string[]>} */
        const insertArray = organize_account_day_setting_data(row, hourlyArray);
        insertArray.forEach(async(insertData) => {
            await insert_account_day_setting(insertData)
            finish_update_count++;
            if ( finish_update_count === insert_total_count) {
                const t2 = new Date().getTime();
                console.log(`${finish_update_count} inserts and all insert finished after ${(t2-t1)/1000} secs`);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

mysql total insert time

[image]

mysql server cpu usage

[image]

[image]

postgresql total insert time

**[image: strong text]**

postgresql server cpu usage

[image]

[image]

Why cause this situation?
How could I tune postgreSQL to use more CPU resource ?

Comment: Does the MySQL-based job complete in less time than the Postgres one does?  That's generally what we mean by "faster", and that one job is more CPU-intensive than the other does not speak directly to that.

Comment: In the (likely) event that the CPU usage genuinely reflects processing throughput, there is a huge number of factors that could be impacting relative performance.  I think you would be better served by focusing on tuning the PG version.  Don't start making comparisons until you're satisfied that it's running as fast as it reasonably can.

Comment: @JohnBollinger

Yes, mysql is use less time than postgresql !!
mysql 3 times faster than postgresql.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Do both MySQL and postgreSQL successfully process all those 300K inserts? If so, it's really good that postgreSQL does the same work as MySQL while using far less CPU.  If not, please give us more details.

Comment: At least share the configuration for your PostgreSQL server and the code that you use to proces this data. Remember, we don't have access to your servers and code.

Comment: @O.Jones  

Thank you guys reply, I modifiy and update more infomation.

Answer (score 0):

Make PostgreSQL exert less stress on the disk by setting `synchronous_commit = off`. Then it has a chance to use more CPU.